# Column contains unsupported column type 'WKT"

Tags: here-api, geofencing, wkt

I am trying to upload a new layer to HERE using the layers/upload.json API, when i try to upload the WKT file, it return me error with this message :"Column name 'STORE_TYPE;*  ADMIN_PLACE_ID  CARTO_ID  WKT' contains unsupported column type 'WKT"

When i tried to delete all the column and put only wkt column, everything will work fine, but when i add a new column for example "ID" then it will return me the same message.
I have tried to use the sample given in the API documentation which shown at below, and the result is still the same.

STORE_TYPE;*  ADMIN_PLACE_ID  CARTO_ID  WKT

13 20300625  75149800  POLYGON ((1.73514 42.5498, 1.73619 42.55064, 1.73663 42.55115, 1.73682 42.55179, 1.73514 42.5498))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the question by declaring the column using TAB instead of Spacebar.

STORE_TYPE;* [TAB] ADMIN_PLACE_ID [TAB] CARTO_ID WKT

13 20300625 [TAB] 75149800 [TAB] POLYGON ((1.73514 42.5498, 1.73619 42.55064, 1.73663 42.55115, 1.73682 42.55179, 1.73514 42.5498))